# any orthogonal system $\{\phi_{\alpha}\}$ in $L^2$ is countable

Tags: real-analysis, orthogonality, separable-spaces

I'm trying to follow the proof of this theorem:

any orthogonal system $\{\phi_{\alpha}\}$ in $L^2$ is countable.

the proof in the book(by Wheeden & Zygmund) is pretty simple; it just shows that $||\phi_{\alpha}-\phi_{\beta}||^2=2$ if $\alpha \neq \beta$ (after assuming the system is orthonormal) and conclude by the separability of $L^2$ space.

I only know the definition of the separable space: if a space is separable, it contains a countable dense subset. but I don't know how to use this to relate with above argument.

Comment: There is at least one definition of a separable Hilbert space that requires it have a countable basis. I suppose however you are proving the equivalence of this definition from that which hypothesizes only the existence of a countable dense subset.

Comment: It is not true. Define $\phi_\alpha = 1_{\alpha}$ for $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @copper.hat In $L^2$ those are all the same function, right?

Comment: @ZacharySelk: I don't understand your question. The Hilbert space I am referring to are the set of functions $f$ such that $\sum_\alpha |f(\alpha)|^2 < \infty$. Some older books (such as Kolmogorov & Fomin) assume separability.

Comment: @copper.hat http://mathworld.wolfram.com/L2-Space.html "Strictly speaking, L^2-space really consists of equivalence classes of functions. Two functions represent the same L^2-function if the set where they differ has measure zero." So your functions, are actually all the same element.

Comment: @ZacharySelk: Thanks, I am familiar with the $L_p$ spaces. In this case the measure is the counting measure. I have a typo. above, I meant to write $1_\{\alpha\}$, the function that is zero everywhere except at $\alpha$ where it is one. Since I am using the counting measure, the equivalence classes contain exactly one function. This is a standard example of a non separable $L_2$ space.

Comment: @copper.hat I assumed they meant with Lebesgue measure. But that should have been clarified.

Comment: @ZacharySelk: Probably, but I think it is a curious space nonetheless, sort of a step up from the counting measure supported on $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @copper.hat It is indeed a curious space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\|a-b\|^2=2$ then the open balls $B(a,1/\sqrt 2\;),\; B(b,1/\sqrt 2)$ are disjoint. Let $F$ be  a non-empty   orthonormal set  and let  $D$ be  a dense set. Then $D$ must have a member $d_f$ in $B(f,1/\sqrt 2)$ for each $f\in F$.  But $d_f\ne d_g$ when $f,g \in F$ with $f\ne g,\;$...(  because $B(f,1/\sqrt 2\;)$ and $B(g,1/\sqrt 2\;)$ are disjoint)... So the cardinal of $D$ is greater than or equal to  the cardinal of $F$. So if $D$ is countable then so is $F$.

Comment: I guess this was what I was looking for. thank you!